# How to separte door handle without visible screws?

Tags: outdoor, lock, doorknob

I need to replace the door handle mechanism because it's stuck. In order to do that, I need to take apart the door handles but there are just two holes under each handle. It doesn't seem that the hole has a screw inside. I tried to put screw-driver inside, it looks like nothing moves then I do that. And a metal round thing around the handle doesn't have any holes to release handles also.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The handle in the top picture has a set screw, visible in the picture - you need an Allen Wrench. Loosen this and the whole thing should come apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That little hole that doesn't have a screw inside actually does have a screw. It's an set screw and needs a special tool to remove it. You'll need a set of allen wrenches. You can pick up a set at your favorite home store.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think about that one

Comment: I was able to remove one side, but the other side doesn't move, neither I can pull out the shaft inside (shaft in a middle which holds both handles). Any suggestions?

Comment: Update you question and add some pictures of what you've got now.

Comment: Fixed the problem, had to spin counter-clockwise metal cover in order to reveal screws. Thanks